# Rendering box shadow around unconventional shapes with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, overflow, css

I'm currently working on a little project in which I'm trying to create a venn diagram representing additive colors. I've started with three circles (border-radius: 50%;) and used a combination of statically-position elements with hidden overflow to create some of the more complex shapes where the circles overlap. You can see what I currently have here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GjvEE/

One feature I'd like to add is the addition of a colored box-shadow around the shape currently being moused-over. The unique challenge I'm facing is presented by the nesting of the elements with hidden overflow, and the need to create 'faux-edges' along which to render the box shadow for each section of the diagram. I've considered the option of simply scrapping this approach and creating the shapes via SVG, but I'm interested to see if any of you have any clever ideas for building this sort of interaction into more complex shapes using traditional HTML and CSS3 alone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: very nice use of data- attributes

Comment: are you wanting to support IE8 or earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using CSS's :after to generate new circles behind the others and use a radial gradient background that fades to transparent?

I've done quick, basic implementations for Webkit on the red and blue circles here. Note the :hover:after style definitions.
http://jsfiddle.net/stevelove/2hpwp/

Comment: I considered using the `:after` pseudoclass, the issue I'd still be grappling with is 'tracing' the edges of those olive shapes I'm creating with the nested elements. Gradients, with the enhanced directional control that they offer, might be a step in the right direction, though.

Comment: Just a follow-up: I've been doing a little research, and it looks like the behavior of `overflow: hidden` on elements with a nonzero `border-radius` is still largely in flux, and varies between web browsers. I suppose SVG, recommended by [HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/#svg) with a polyfill for older browsers, is  a bit more viable as a solution than I'd originally thought. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: No problem. It was a fun way to spend a few spare minutes.